# adding image upload to iframe rte

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a question on inserting an image into a simple text editor that's loaded as an iframe, i have coded it simply, here is the markup:

```
 <iframe id="textEditor" style="width:500px; height:170px;" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

and here's the javascript that goes with it:

```
textEditor.document.designMode="on";
textEditor.document.open();
textEditor.document.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font- size:13px; }</style> </head>');
textEditor.document.close();
```

the other options are there but not relevant, for instance, here's the code for font-control:
  markup:

```
   <select id="fonts" onChange="fontEdit('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
   <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
   <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
   <option value="Monotype Corsiva">Monotype</option>
   <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
   <option value="Times">Times</option>
   </select>
```

javascript:

```
 function fontEdit(x,y)
{
textEditor.document.execCommand(x,"",y);
textEditor.focus();
}
```

and so on, along with other options for font size, color etc. The question is, how would i add image-upload functionality to this? So that the user can upload an image in the editor whenever they want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax like upload then you need to use another iframe for that or you can use library for that like [ajax-upload](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) and in onComplete event you can create image in your editor.